# Counting the number of lines of text in all files within a folder and subfolders using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a huge folder with subfolders and multiple .sql files within those subfolders. I want to get the number of lines of code within every .sql file. This is what I've tried:

```
import os
import glob
os.chdir("path of folder")
names=[]
for fn in glob.glob("*.sql"):
    with open(fn) as f:
    names[fn]=sum(1 for line in f if line.strip() and not line.startswith('#'))    

print(names)
```

But the output I get is [ ]. Could you guys help me with where I'm going wrong?

I know how to count the number of lines of code within a single file using "num_lines". I can't do that manually for each file and need to quicken the process.

Answer (score 1):

The following version of you code works for files in the target directory, but not sub-folders:

```
import os
import glob

os.chdir("foo")
names = {}
for fn in glob.glob("*.sql"):
    with open(fn) as f:
        names[fn] = sum(1 for line in f if line.strip() and not line.startswith('#'))

print(names)
```

A version with the newer `pathlib` works recursively too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path

target = Path("foo")

names = {}

for file in target.glob("**/*.sql"):
    with file.open("rt") as f:
        names[f.name] = sum(
            1 for line in f
            if line.strip() and not line.startswith('#')
        )

print(names)
```

Comment: You can also make `glob.glob` recursive by setting the `recursive` flag to `True` and adding `**/` to the path: `glob.glob("**/*.sql", recursive=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sql_folder_path = "full/path/to/sql/folder"
sql_files = [join(sql_folder_path, f) for f in listdir(sql_folder_path) if isfile(join(sql_folder_path, f)) and f.endswith(".sql")]
files_stats = {}
for file in sql_files:
    with open(file) as f:
        files_stats[file]=sum(1 for line in f if line.strip() and not line.startswith('#'))
print(files_stats)
```